# SimpleXML UTF8 in import

Tags: php, simplexml

everybody,

I am trying to create my own XML import script but I have problem with character "š,č,ř,ě". My script look like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$products = $xml->SHOPITEM;
$options = $products->VARIANT->var; 
$product_name = $products->PRODUCTNAME)
var_dump($product_name);
exit();
```

When I dump $product_name the result looks like this: "FIRST CLASS ĹˇedĂ©". As you can see character where is "ěščřžýáíí" is broken.

Thank you for help.

Comment: How does your XML file look? Does it have <?xml> header?

Comment: Yes header of my XML file look like this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: Then thats just a browser selecting a wrong encoding I think. Try changing browser encoding or adding header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); before var_dump()

Comment: Thank donis thas is exactly what I am looking for. Your solution works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To post as an answer - thats just a browser selecting a wrong encoding. All the characters returned are correct but the browser shows them with a wrong encoding.
Try changing browser encoding or adding header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); before var_dump()